# How to get the underlying html source for a Multipart mail

Tags: java, html, email, jakarta-mail

I have a requirement to parse an incoming multipart mail and get the inline attachments from the mail.

This part is already done where I am able to extract all the inline attachments from the mail using javamail api. But there are few attachments which are embedded in the mail and are not required. I have to find those attachments and filter them out(examples : like avatar image)

For example:

```
<img width=564 height=419 id="_x0020_1" src="cid:image005.jpg@01D0E4C9.BDF788A0">

<img border=0 width=32 height=32 id=avatar-image src="cid:image006.png@01D0E4C9.BDF788A0">

<img border=0 width=16 height=16 id="_x0000_i1087" src="cid:image007.png@01D0E4C9.BDF788A0">
```

So as can be seen from the above three image source from mail, I would require the first and third image while the second is not required. So I would have to filter it out. The only way to differentiate it from others is by the id of the img tag.

So if somehow I can get this html source of the image then I can parse it and then filter it out accordingly. I tried out few options but nothing seemed to work out.

Can someone point me to some way on how this can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to get the html content of the message, see [this JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody).

But maybe I don't understand what you mean by "html source of the **image**".

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I guess I overlooked the document. Thanks for your reply Bill.